# Resizable elements in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, polymer

I tried to make a component for resizable cards using paper-dialog, and
I tried to use the css property "resize:both;" but I couldnt find a way to update interior elements and components when their container (paper-dialog) increases in size. Is there a way to capture the resize event on an element? When I do, what should i call/do to trigger the css update?

Thanks!

Comment: They added recently a core-resizable mixin in the 0.5.2 version, you can find more info in this links:

https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2014/12/12/release-0.5.2/
https://github.com/Polymer/core-resizable
http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~mjbill/components/core-resizable/#CoreResizer

Answer (score 3):

With Polymer 1.x there is a corresponding behaviour for handling element resizing -- `Polymer.IronResizableBehavior`. [Here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-resizable-behavior/blob/master/demo/src/x-app.html) is a good example that demonstrates how it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Elements don't have a resize event. This is something that's missing from the web platform. On window can have a resize event.

One thing you can do is use mouse events to fake it and know when the user has done the resize. `mouseup` is the hook to know when the resize is done:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="my-element" on-mouseup="{{resizeDone}}">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        background: red;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        resize:both;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
    width: <span>{{width}}</span>
    height: <span>{{height}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      attached: function() {
        this.resizeDone(null, null, this);
      },
      resizeDone: function(e, detail, sender) {
        this.width = sender.clientWidth;
        this.height = sender.clientHeight;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element></my-element>
```